# How do I hook up a submit button with my rails database and save it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, submit

I'm trying to hook up this line of code, which is a submit button, to the database in my rails app. I thought after giving it the post method it would save.

I've tried giving it parameters of (@message) trying to be specific

Here is the lines for the button:

```
<%= link_to 'Submit', messages_path(@message), method: :post, class: 'btn-submit' %>
```

Here is the controller:

```
def create
    Message.create(message_params)
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

The page just reloads currently without saving the data.

Comment: this was supposed to be in the question:   <%= link_to 'Submit', messages_path(@message), method: :post, class: 'btn-submit' %>

Answer (score 0):

It would be realy helpfull if you attached your `Message` model code and `routes.rb` file. But anyway... I'll try to explain.

Ussually developers use forms to submit data. To create `Message` object you need to pass some data from your view. [More about forms](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html). Your view need to look like this:

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :text, class: 'form-control' %> // you need to change it t be a field of your Message model
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn-submit' %> // this is your submit button
<% end %>
```

in your controller add conditions to check if message was created. [More info](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#create)

```
def create
  if Message.create(message_params)
    redirect_to root_path # redirect to root path if message created
  else
    render :new # render action :new in case of errors.
  end
end
```

Make sure you pass all data required to pass `Message` model [validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#validations) if you have any.

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

also you should check what url the form is posting too in your rails console

You can check what paths you have available by running in the terminal

`rake routes | grep message`

this should return all the routes which contain message.
make sure its going to the right one and matches!